# Rendering too many points on Javascript-player

Tags: javascript, video, optimization

As part of a project, I have to render a video on a JS-player from a text file which has the points - all the changed coordinates along-with the color in each frame. Below is the code I'm using to draw these point on the screen.

But the issue is that the number of changed pixels in each frame are as high as ~20,000 and I need to display these in less than 30ms (inter-frame time difference). So, when I run this code the browser hangs for almost each frame. Could someone suggest an improvement for this?

Any help is really appreciated.

```
c.drawImage(img,0,0,800,800);
    setInterval(
        function(){
            while(tArr[index]==time) {
                var my_imageData = c.getImageData(0,0,width, height);
                color(my_imageData,Math.round(yArr[index]),Math.round(xArr[index]),Math.round(iArr[index]),255);
                c.putImageData(my_imageData,0,0);
                index=index+1;
            }
            time = tArr[index];
        }
    ,30);
```

xArr, yArr, iArr, tArr are arrays of x-coordinate, y-coordinate, intensity value and time of appearance respectively for the corresponding point to be rendered

```
function color(imageData,x,y,i,a){  //wrapper function to color the point
    var index = (x + y * imageData.width) * 4;
    imageData.data[index+0] = i;
    imageData.data[index+1] = i;
    imageData.data[index+2] = i;
    imageData.data[index+3] = a;
}
```